# How to get localStorage value on client-side from global middleware using Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, local-storage, server-side-rendering

I have implemented functionality for change theme between dark and light in my `Nuxt.js` project, but I have one more problem.

After user changes in setting theme he gets flag in local storage. Flag `_t` (theme) and values - `_d` is for dark and `_l` is lor light. Depending on these values script has to set attribute `data-theme` to dark or light and then, depending on `scss` variables theme will be set.

The problem is - how can I get this value from `localStorage`. Of course, on every page I can create `mounted()` hook and check for value in `localStorage`, but I have to do this on every page I create and it doesn't seem to be normal solution. I was thinking about global middleware and created one.

```
export default function() {
  if (process.server) return
  const t = localStorage.getItem('_t')
  if (!t) {
    localStorage.setItem('_t', '_d')
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', t === '_l' ? 'light' : 'dark')
  }
}
```

I works, but not quite right. `Nuxt.js` works with SSR, so basically the first time middleware is called on server, and only then on client side. That's why I have this `if (process.server)` check, because `localStorage` is unavailable on server side.

The problem of this solution is, after page reload you won't see in `HTLM` this `data-theme="dark"`. And because of this, styles seem to be 'broken'. It works only if you go to this page by clicking on `nuxt-link`, because it works on client side.

So, what would be the best practice in this case. Is any opportunity to implement this check globally and not to check for `localStorage` value in `mounted()` hook on every page?

Comment: can you try storing the theme-settings in vuex store and persist it so you directly access it from the vuex store?

Comment: I don't event think that you need a middleware here, there are probably other ways to solve this issue. Also, you could use this module for a simple implementation of dark/light mode: https://color-mode.nuxtjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach but instead of using `localStorage` you can use `cookies`, as `cookies` are sent via every HTTP request, so you can access it on the server-side and client side.

You can use this library for managing your cookies.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt

For more resources about cookies.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie